# What is meaning of nn.Parameter

Tags: pytorch

I'm working in GCN with pytorch. and I can find code that

```
weight = nn.Parameter(torch.FloatTensor(in_features, out_features))
```

Does this code set the weight to a random value?

If it is, then

```
weight = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(size=(in_features, out_features)))
```

Does this just set the initial value to zero matrix instead of a random value?

I also wonder what code update weight.

Comment: Did the answer below give an answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

[`nn.Parameter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.parameter.Parameter.html) are used in [`nn.Module`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=nn%20module#torch.nn.Module) to define tensors as child modules. This has the effect of registering that tensor as a parameter of the module (which will appear in the `.parameters()` generator). By default, the provided tensor will have its `requires_grad` set to `True`. You can pass any tensor to it (`torch.FloatTensor` is random initialized, yes).

```
class F(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.theta = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor([1.,2.,1.]))
```

Then `.parameters()` will contain that tensor:

```
>>> next(F().parameters())
Parameter containing:
tensor([1., 2., 1.], requires_grad=True)
```

Notice however that if you do not assign that `nn.Parameter` to a property of that class Module, then the tensor won't be registered.